# I'm trying to update Debian Bullseye packages using apt update

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, repository

when I type the following I get this

```
jerry@debian:~$ sudo apt update 
[sudo] password for jerry:          
Ign:1 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux bullseye-DI-rc1 _Bullseye_ - Unofficial amd64 DVD Binary-1 with firmware 20210415-20:27] bullseye InRelease
Err:2 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux bullseye-DI-rc1 _Bullseye_ - Unofficial amd64 DVD Binary-1 with firmware 20210415-20:27] bullseye Release
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease [146 kB]
Hit:4 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian bullseye InRelease          
Hit:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux bullseye-DI-rc1 _Bullseye_ - Unofficial amd64 DVD Binary-1 with firmware 20210415-20:27] bullseye Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-large (main/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-large (main/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:4
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:4
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons-large (main/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:4
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:5
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:5
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:5
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:5
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:5
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:5
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:5
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:5
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:5
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:5
W: Target DEP-11-icons-large (main/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:5
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-large (main/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-large (main/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:4
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:4
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons-large (main/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:4
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:5
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:5
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:5
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:5
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:5
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:5
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:5
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:5
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:5
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:5
W: Target DEP-11-icons-large (main/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:5
jerry@debian:~$
```

Answer (score 4):

Comment or delete the `deb cdrom:` line at the top of `/etc/apt/sources.list` to get rid of the error message and remove all duplicate entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list` to get rid of the warning messages.